# I'm getting an error 'The method selectByVisibleText(String) is undefined for the type WebElement'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting this error while coding

```
The method selectByVisibleText(String) is undefined for the type WebElement
```

and also I have tried to import this -->

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

But it fails. The code is given below,

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Service")).selectByVisibleText("Broadband"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.AddBtnServiceAssignment")).click();
```

HTML Code:

```
<!--Wizard 1--> <tr> <td>select</td> <td>id=Service</td> <td>label=Broadband</td> </tr> <tr> <td>click</td> <td>css=input.AddBtnServiceAssignment</td> <td></td> </tr> <tr>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML and check whether it have value parameter or not

Comment: <!--Wizard 1-->
<tr>
 <td>select</td>
 <td>id=Service</td>
 <td>label=Broadband</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>css=input.AddBtnServiceAssignment</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>

Comment: Please share URL , I dont see select class over there

Comment: oops. I'm sorry to say... This can be available in our local area network. I've testing in a local testing port.

Comment: Can u paste complete code from Select class to the values of drop down

Comment: selectByVisibleText is not a method of webelement class but of select class. You are misplacing brackets. try this -- new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Service"))).selectByVisibleText("Broadband");

Comment: @iamsankalp89 - package TalkTalkPackage; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class TalkTalkClass { 
public void testADSL2() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://Driver//chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://83.137.180.215:1000/ServiceAssignment/Index/4/5598");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Service")).selectByVisibleText("Broadband"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.AddBtnServiceAssignment")).click();
}}

Comment: Please tell @SudeepKrishna

Comment: @Grasshopper - let me check

Comment: Oops. This is a table data . You can see that the tags or tr and td not select and options. You need to treat the way as you treat the table data. First expand the table by clicking on it normally. Then click the table data. Using select class is not relevant here and it wont work. Let me know if you need more clear hints.